# how to obtain a file in an interactive bash shell session

Tags: bash, scp, download

Not sure if I ask this correctly. I am doing some pentest practice, and in a bash shell session, I want to download a file.

I tried `cp` to that machine, but it just creates a file in the current directory. I even host a temporary server from my attacker machine using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`, but I just couldn't extract the file I want.

Is there any simple one line command I can do this with? I just need a short line to take this file back to my attacker machine so I can use this command again in future whenever I pawn a host.

Comment: Is `mount`ing the remote drive an option? In other words, by `mount`ing the remote drive, you would be able to use `cp` to copy files from the `mount`ed drive/folder to your local filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy a file to target host:

```
scp file user@host:/destinationdir/
```

To copy a file from source host to your current directory:

```
scp user@host:/sourcedir/file .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scp` to, but I would use mercurial (`hg`) and bit-bucket: I would revision control all of my files with mercurial, I would then synchronise it with bit-bucket, so that I could pull the files to any machine that I want. It also provides a backup.

If you don't want to use bit-bucket, you can enable a local mercurial server, and pull from that.